# Excel Formula or Macro to get the consolidated list from two tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Question:

**Table 1** is as follows.

```
Name   |    Hours     
john   |    12     
mark   |    20   
john   |    10   
mark   |    10
```

**Table 2** is as follows.

```
Name   |    Hours        
john   |    40     
mark   |    30
```

These 2 tables are in two diffent workbooks. The Data I need is as follows.

**Step 1:** From Table 1 I need to consolidate the Column 'Name' and should get the SUm of Column 'Hours'. (i.e) it should be populated as follows.

**Table 3**

```
Name   |    Hours         
john   |    22  
mark   |    30
```

**Step 2:** Once the above step is achieved I should compare the Column 'Hours' in Table 2 & Table 3 and should populated the result as true or false..

Comment: Try `IF()` and `SUMIF()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(SUMIF([Workbook1]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$4;A1,[Workbook1]Sheet1!$B$1:$B$4)=B1,"true","false")
```

It assumes that Table1 is in Workbook1, Sheet1 in range `A1:B4`.

I also assumed that Table2 locates in `A1:B2` range. Now it's enough to place above formula in C1 cell next to Table2 and drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

Create two pivot tables for both tables and compare accordingly. Then,

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Hours",$A$2,"Name",A3)=GETPIVOTDATA("Hours",$A$8,"Name",A9)
```

[image]